# Take photo on Android tablet not working

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I can successfully take a photo on an Android phone but not on a Nexus 10 tablet.  The tablet returns a null value even though I took a picture.  To initiate the photo take I use the following code:

```
                String fileName = "myimage.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
                startActivityForResult( intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

And my code on returning from taking the photo looks like this:

```
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Log.d("selectedImage=", String.valueOf(selectedImage));
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

The activity returns a null value for selectedImage when using the Nexus tablet but returns a valid value for the Samsung Galaxy 4.  What could be different between the 2 devices and how do I accommodate the differences?  I should note that when taking a photo with the tablet, the photo is not placed in my gallery either.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might want to try passing the 'EXTRA_OUTPUT' as recommended in the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE   Is your Nexus already running Lollipop?